# HTML Canvas inside html canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

How do you use a canvas as a canvas container for more canvases? I am new to web dev, but I have tried several things. This looks like it should work but doesn't. The goal is to have a canvas, with many images, then a canvas ontop of images to draw text/items.

```
<canvas id="canvas1">
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like canvases, so we put a canvas in your canvas so you can canvas while you're canvassin'

Comment: @j08691 Love your comment even though it doesn't technically add anything useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not nest canvases, but you can insert a text for browsers that does not support canvas:

```
<canvas>
    Sorry, no canvas for you dawg
</canvas>
```

To stack canvases:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:someWidth;heigth:someHeight;">
    <canvas id="c1" width=w .. style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c2" width=w .. style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c3" width=w .. style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a canvas element is exactly what it's called - a canvas. Once you have a canvas you don't have elements anymore, you have a drawing so it doesn't make sense to put a canvas inside a canvas, rather draw everything you want on that one canvas.

Answer (score 0):

How about initializing multiple canvas in different containers, but also different layers?

```
<canvas id="bg" width="X" height="Y" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0">
</canvas>
<canvas id="fg" width="X" height="Y" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1">
</canvas>
```